# Which Stage is used to Combine Two Data Stream without Common Key Field in DataStage (IBM)

Tags: datastage

I'm using Data Stage version 11.7 and encountered the error message below from the Lookup stage while compiling the job:

"The supplied expression was empty."

In the Lookup Stage, there are two links from two transformers and there is no common key column between the two datasets.

I googled how to merge or combine the two datasets from two transformers without a common key column. However, I couldn't find a proper way to solve this issue or the way implementing my job in DataStage.
[Empty Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgswP.jpg)

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem? If so, please let me know which stage is good for my job or how to solve the error. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to join `n:m`, add a dummy column to each input link and fill it with a constant value like `1`. Then join over that column. Decide if mutiple matches result in mutiple output rows or if the first match 'wins' - which would be like a random n:1 then, since every row matches when joining over a const value.

But if you need to join specific rows, it indicates that there actually *is* a common key but it's not obvious or visible. Either Transform the sources so that they get a common key or use an anchor table that provides the relations. Join that to the first source, then join the second source.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your experience and knowledge for my problem solving, Justus Kenklies. I will definitely try it out.